# How can I refetch/update my api data in my future builder in flutter

Tags: flutter

I initially fetched from an api (**PrimeTimesFetchByLocation.dart**) in the **LocationBasedPrimeTimes.dart** then show the prime times using the futurebuilder. But thing is I update my fetch and reload the futurebuilder from the **settingsUI.dart** after I made sub changes then hit **_handleSubmit**.  I tried but don't know how can I achieve that.

Here is my code snippet.

---

From Settings.dart (want to update the initially fetched prime times again by using city ID)

```
class _BasedPrimeTimesState extends State<BasedPrimeTimes> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Color(0xFFFFFBF8),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
             Builder(
           builder: (context) => Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _loading
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            // Call the submit function when button is pressed
                            final String cityName = _cityInputValue;
                            final int? cityId =
                                null; // Assuming this value should be fetched from somewhere
                            final String countryName = _inputValue;
                            final SharedPreferences prefs =
                                await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                            final int? countryId =
                                prefs.getInt('countryId_$countryName');
    
                            setState(() {
                              _loading = true;
                            });
    
                            await _handleSubmit(
                                cityName, cityId, countryName, countryId);
    
                            setState(() {
                              _loading = false;
                            });
                          },
                    child: _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }


      Future<void> _handleSubmit(
          String cityName, int? cityId, String countryName, int? countryId) async {
        if (cityName.isNotEmpty && countryName.isNotEmpty) {
          final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.setInt('cityId', cityId ?? 0);
        } else {
          _showSnackbar('Error: City or Country is empty', true);
        }
      }
    }
```

---

LocationBasedPrimeTimes.dart ( Want to update the prime times here)

```
class _LocationBasedPrimeTimesState extends State<LocationBasedPrimeTimes> {
  late Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _primeTimesFuture;
  final primeTimesFetcher = PrimeTimesFetcher();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _primeTimesFuture = primeTimesFetcher.loadCityIdAndFetchPrimeTimes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                future: _primeTimesFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError && snapshot.error != null) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError && snapshot.error == null) {
                    return Text('Unknown Error');
                  } else {
                    Map<String, dynamic> primeTimes = snapshot.data!;
                  );
                 }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

From PrimeTimesFetchByLocation.dart ( Initially fetching the  prime times here)

```
class PrimeTimesFetcher {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadCityIdAndFetchPrimeTimes() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int? cityId = prefs.getInt('cityId');

    if (cityId != null) {
      return fetchPrimeTimes(cityId);
    } else {
      throw Exception('City ID not available in SharedPreferences.');
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPrimeTimes(int cityId) async {
    final String url = 'some-api/city';
    final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
      "cityId": cityId,
    };

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String currentMonthYear = DateFormat('yyyy-MM').format(now);
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> cachedPrimeTimes =
        await LocalDatabase.getPrimeTimesByMonth(currentMonthYear);

    if (cachedPrimeTimes.isNotEmpty) {
      return cachedPrimeTimes.first;
    }

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> primeTimesData = responseData['primeTimes'];
      String currentDate =
          DateFormat('EEEE dd MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.now());

      Map<String, dynamic>? currentPrimeTimes;
      for (var primeTime in primeTimesData) {
        if (primeTime['date'] == currentDate) {
          currentPrimeTimes = primeTime;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (currentPrimeTimes != null) {
        await LocalDatabase.locationBasedInsertPrimeTimes(
            LocationBasedPrimeTimesModel.fromJson(currentPrimeTimes),
            currentMonthYear);

        return currentPrimeTimes;
      } else {
        throw 'Prime times not available for $currentDate.';
      }
    } else {
      throw 'Failed to fetch prime times.';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the LocationBasedPrimeTimes widget, data is only loaded when the initState is executed. In this scenario, if you update the city and the initState of LocationBasedPrimeTimes is not executed again, you will not see any updates.

The initState is an integral method of the widget lifecycle, and it is the first method to be called when a StatefulWidget class is instantiated, and it is called only once for each instance.

There are two approaches to fixing the problem:

1. Using navigation: Assuming that LocationBasedPrimeTimes is one page and SettingsUI is another, you can navigate between them using pushReplacement. This way, every time you return to LocationBasedPrimeTimes, a new instance will necessarily be created, and consequently, the initState will be called, since pushReplacement replaces one widget with another (instead of stack them). This does not happen if you navigate from LocationBasedPrimeTimes to SettingsUI with just a push, or do not navigate, because in these cases the LocationBasedPrimeTimes widget will not be destroyed and rebuilt.
2. State management: There are many ways and numerous packages for this (which can have several advantages, mainly related to code maintainability). However, I will explain with setState. In this case, every time you update SharedPreferences, you must call loadCityIdAndFetchPrimeTimes or fetchPrimeTimes inside the LocationBasedPrimeTimes widget through the _primeTimesFuture variable, within a setState, so any update related to modification will be reflective of the UI, and the futureBuilder will identify the new states of the snapshot. This does not happen in the current scenario because the future state of the _primeTimesFuture variable is only modified when the initState is called. To update the _primeTimesFuture variable and call the setState through another widget, you can pass a callback function through the constructors. Where do you create a function that updates the _primeTimesFuture within a setState in the LocationBasedPrime widget, and pass it in the constructor of the SettingsUI, calling it when the city is updated in the SettingsUI. You also can call this when the future of Navigator is complete. Another way would be to use InheritedWidget.

Example of callback:

```
Future<void> _handleSubmit(
    String cityName, int? cityId, String countryName, int? countryId, RefreshCallback refreshCallback) async {
    // Existing code to save city details
    // ...
    // After updating the city, call the callback to refresh the LocationBasedPrimeTimes
    refreshPrimeTimes();
}

class _LocationBasedPrimeTimesState extends State<LocationBasedPrimeTimes> {
  // Existing code
  // ...

  // Method to refresh prime times
  void refreshPrimeTimes() {
    setState(() {
      _primeTimesFuture = primeTimesFetcher.loadCityIdAndFetchPrimeTimes();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed settings.dart for better understanding. I am quite confused where I put this in RefreshCallback refreshCallback in the settings.dart. I updated the code.

Comment: The refreshPrimeTimes method should be implemented in the _LocationBasedPrimeTimesState class, and invoked in the class responsible for updating the city. To call this function from another class, you will need to pass it through the constructor of the class where it will be used.

Comment: Could you show me implementation?